# How can I add a dependency in poetry using ~ tilde instead of ^ caret?

Tags: python, python-poetry

When I use the command:

```
poetry add djangorestframework
```

The generated result always uses caret:

```
djangorestframework = "^3.11.0"
```

For my context, caret is very aggressive, so I would like to add the dependencies using tilde.

How can I instruct poetry to use tilde?

**Alternative 1**: it works, but I have to search for the most current version first and then add it.

```
poetry add djangorestframework~3.11.0
```

**Alternative 2**: does not work, syntax error

```
poetry add djangorestframework~latest
```

Comment: I think you're just supposed to edit the `pyproject.toml` file. The .toml format was chosen so that editing by hand would be no problem (as opposed in, say, a json file), and poetry just picks caret as the default. Learning sub-commands or flags for other version modifiers would be more complicated than just editing the file, so why clutter the CLI?

Comment: Hey @Arne, basically my point is that the workflow "1 - add a dependency; 2 - edit pyproject.toml manually" is very susceptible to errors and forgetfulness. It would be much better to have this option on the command line.

Comment: Furthermore, I particularly believe that caret is not a good default, I find it very aggressive. I think that if it is not possible to choose between one or the other directly on the command line, the default should be more conservative as using simply "dep = version" without the possibility of automatic updates.

Comment: The lockfile will prevent automatic updates, which is why in general people are fine with caret as the default. Using dep = version has downsides as well, but you can also post it as an issue [to github](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues) if you are convinced that you are right and open the discuss and defend the point.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `~` modifier is relative to some version, poetry needs you to say what version that is. Poetry doesn't have a way to find the latest version number then apply the `~` to that number as recorded in pyproject.toml.

So your two choices are:

1 -- use `poetry add whatever~3.11.0` as in your Alternative 1.

2 -- use `poetry add whatever` with no version specified, wait for that to be installed, then edit the pyproject.toml file to change the `^` to a `~` or whatever your version requirement is for that particular library.

There's nothing wrong with editing pyproject.toml.